# Error: the chosen directory does not contain the required product while installing STS

Tags: spring-tool-suite

While installing STS using installer, I was asked to select the JDK path:

[image]

I used the following command to get the jdk path:

[image]

However it shows the error:
**The chosen directory does not contain the required product**

[image]

Please advice.

Comment: It looks like you are using a quite old and outdated version of the tool suite. The recent versions don't come with an installer... If there isn't a really good reason to use that old STS version, I would recommend to install a newer version, which you can download from https://spring.io/tools

Answer (score 1):

Somebody solved selecting path up to JDK directory (removing final bin).

Otherwise try downloading zip file instead of installer and unzip it somewhere (not in Program Files).
Then you can configure it manually setting the "-vm c:\pathtojdk\bin\javaw.exe" argument in STS.ini.